# Multiplying Rabbits python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program for multiplying rabbits every month, I know there's already questions about it but I can't find something that makes sense to me, I'm new to python so I can't do a lot of advanced stuff. This is my code so far. Every month, a pair of rabbits has 4 bunnies, so after one month there are 6 rabbits, after two months there's 18, and after three months there's 54.

```
months=input("Enter number of months:")
total=0
while months>0:
  total=months*4+2
  total=total+((total/2)*4)
  print (total)
```

Comment: your code seems fine to me in terms of syntax. What is your question?

Comment: what if all the rabbits are male?

Comment: I guess you should remove `total=months*4+2` and replace `while months>0` with `for _ in range(int(months))`.

Comment: You need to covert `input` from string to int and your loop is infinite as written.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun It's giving me an error, I also didn't think they way I did was correct.

Comment: `total = 2` then `for i in range(int(input('"Enter number of months:"')): total += (total/2)*4`

Comment: Also, note that `(totals/2)*4` is the same as `totals*2`, although the former my be closer to the statement in the question.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, your loop is wrong. You don't decrease `months`, so you have an infinite loop.

Pay attention to what the problem states. Let's call the number of initial rabbits `total`. Every month, each pair (`total / 2`) produces 4 offsprings. So, the total number of rabbits is `total + (total / 2) * 4`, which is simplified to `total * 3`. That's after one more month. You can either write a loop to multiply `total` by 3 for each month, or just outright do `total * 3**months`.

```
>>> def rabbit_population(initial_pop, months):
    return initial_pop * 3**months

>>> rabbit_population(2, 3)
54
>>>
```

Comment: The solution assumes a non-negative integer number for both the initial number of rabbits and the reproduction duration. Criteria validation would be required for a more complete solution. And if the number of rabbits is odd, remove one from the initial population, do the calculations and then add it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want

```
months=int(input("Enter number of months:"))
print((3**months)*2)
```

Output:

```
Enter number of months:3
54
```

I just raised 3 to number of months and multiplied it by 2